# python global variable, whats going on here? Explanation needed

Tags: python

Can someone explain what's going on here

```
x = 10
def foo():
    print "x in foo = ",x
    if x: x = 8    -------------> mysterious line

foo()
print "x in main = ",x
```

In the above code, If i comment out the mysterious line (if x: x = 8)

I get the output

```
x in foo =  10
x in main =  10
```

Otherwise I end up with error

> "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"

Why so?

I know `global x` is helpful only when I need to modify a global variable locally.

Comment: But you *are* modifying `x` locally.

Comment: What variables from which scopes are available in a function is determined when the function is "compiled." That is, a variable can't go from being global to local in the middle of `foo()`.

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you make an assignment to `x` anywhere in the function, it becomes a local variable, even if there are references to its value prior to the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

In your function, you assign to `x` with no `global` declaration, so `x` is a local variable. However, you attempt to read `x` in the function before it's assigned to, so you have an unbound local at that point.

Answer (score 2):

What may seem strange at first is that **local names are detected statically**: if the name `x` is assigned **anywhere** in the function, Python assumes that `x` is a local name **everywhere** in the function.

In other words, the line order in your function is misleading: as long as `x` is assigned somewhere in the function, the first line's `x` becomes a reference to a local variable (which at this code point is still unbound).

Comment: I have one more doubt if "Python assumes that x is a local name everywhere in the function", then why locals() in below code is not printing "x" as local var

    x = 10

    def foo():
        print locals()
        print "x in foo = ",x
        if x:x = 8


    foo()
    print "x in main = ",x

Comment: @narendra_l: `locals()` only returns actually bound names in the local namespace; the interpreter knows that the name in that namespace can only be a local at compile time, even if it's not bound at the time you run `locals()`.

Comment: @Wooble:you mean 'x' is not bounded to local namespace when compiler executes locals()?

Comment: There is no name `x` in the local symbol table until it's assigned to. (This is exactly what UnboundLocalError means).

Answer (score 1):

Like Wooble already said, you need to declare the modifikation of a global variable before usage.

```
def foo():  
   global x  
   print "x in foo = ",x  
   if x: x = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

`x = 8` anywhere in the function without `global x` makes it a local variable. `print x` fails because a local variable is not initialized